# Have a problem with bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

```
\documentclass [a4paper]{dissert}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
%\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{prabib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ukrthesis4}
%\newcommand{\be}{\begin{split}}
%\newcommand{\ee}{\end{split}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Моя Модель}

Діраківські ферміони (спін $\frac{1}{2}$ врах?) в $2+1$ розмірності, що можуть рухатись вільно в площині (планарна модель)


\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\label{Li}
  \mbox{Li}_2 \left(-e^{- \frac{\mu+ \Delta}{ T}} \right) - \mbox{Li}_2 \left(-e^{ \frac{\mu- \Delta}{T}}\right)=
  & 2\mbox{Li}_2 \left(-e^{-\frac{\mu+ \Delta}{ T}} \right)+\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\ln^{2}\left(e^{ \frac{\mu- \Delta}{T}}\right)\\
  &\simeq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mu- \Delta}{ T}\right)^{2}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliographystyle{gost780u}
\bibliographystyle{1}

\end{document}
```

In `1.bib` items are organized as follows :

```
@BOOK{Ask,
  author =       {Б. М. Аскеров},
  title =        {ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ ЯВЛЕНИЯ ПЕРЕНОСА В ПОЛУПРОВОДНИКАХ},
  publisher =    {Наука. Гл. ред. физ.-мат. лит.,}
  year =         { 1985},
    pages =        {320},
```

But do not compile..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I would start by replacing `\bibliographystyle{1}` with `\bibliography{1}`. Then, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Incidentally, the `dissert` document class doesn't appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Can it be obtained online?

Comment: i have it on my computer. How can i make it available online? i don't know

Comment: if  i change the dissert class to article  -  but there my picture (.eps)  do not display . What should be done??

Comment: or, i managed to make bibliography - \bibliography{99} - but i cat make numeration - so \cite{} does not work  - in disert class-

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, but looks to me like missing comma as the last character of publisher line